# What type of graphics processor is NVAC?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

In Settings under About, the graphics processor reported is 'NVAC'. What does this mean? What kind of graphics processor is NVAC? [Ubuntu Settings About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JilyD.png)

Also reported by glxinfo.
[glxinfo -B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olD9k.png)

I had expected to see something like 'IntelHD' or 'Nvidia' or something but it says "NVAC" so I'm wondering what this means.